# Showing a limit is infinity. How to compute it?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to compute: $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{ \sin x }{x^2} $ and $ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{ \cos x }{x^3}$. For the first one, since $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \sin x}{x} = 1 $, we have that

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{ \sin x}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{x} = 1 \cdot \infty = \infty $$

For the other one, can I just say that as $x \to 0^+$, the function approaches

$$ \cos 0 \times \infty = \infty $$
??

thanks

Comment: And what if $\cos(0) = 0$?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp ?!

Comment: I just wanted to point out that one has to be careful here. Of course, $\cos(0) = 1$, so the limit computation is valid.

Comment: You can also use maclaurin expansion for sin and cos

Comment: @Albas using $\cos 0 = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ is equivalent to Taylor/MacLaurin expansions to order $0$ and $1$, respectively -- but does not require to even know what a Taylor/MacLaurin expansion is.

Comment: @Albas: Sure. Let's get more complicated. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Your first proof is alright: another (more detailed/hair-splitting) would be to say that since $\frac{\sin x}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to0^+]{} 1$, you have $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\frac{\sin x}{x} > \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x\in(0,\varepsilon)$, and then you get for $x\in(0,\varepsilon)$ that
$$\frac{\sin x}{x^2} \geq \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{x} \xrightarrow[x\to0^+]{} \infty.
$$

For the second, this is similar: $\cos x\xrightarrow[x\to0^+]{} 1$, so there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\cos x > \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x\in(0,\varepsilon)$, and then for $x\in(0,\varepsilon)$ you get
$$\frac{\cos x}{x^3} \geq \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{x^3} \xrightarrow[x\to0^+]{} \infty.
$$